# how to add line markers to chart?

Tags: vb.net

how i can add markers to chart and control it,the second problem is that the area chart not continue untill the end of X axis points.i want it to complete even the end points is zero.i attched the image below

this my chart which i get
http://www.mediafire.com/view/h3n5ekq12l8kloc/ice_screenshot_20190914-142739.png
 i want chart to look as that picture with dashed line markers
http://www.mediafire.com/view/dcaei05625idbwl/ice_screenshot_20190903-151243.png

Answer (score 0):

i solved the second problem to make the chart continue even in empty values.bu using this code after adding values to X and Y axis

```
      `For Each s As Series In PlatChart.Series
        For Each dp As DataPoint In s.Points
            If dp.YValues(0) = 0 Then
                dp.MarkerSize = 5
                dp.MarkerStyle = MarkerStyle.Diamond
                dp.MarkerColor = s.Color
            End If
          Next
          Next`
```